# alphabetically paginate users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, alphabetical

I am trying to create an alphabetical pagination for rails. I have found some plugins and gems but they come up with errors so I am trying to create a custom pagination which isn't working quite right...WHy is this?

model(userrrrrr.rb)
    def self.find_by_group
    ('A'..'Z').map do |letter| 
      @users = User.find_by_sql(:all, :conditions=>['LOWER(name) LIKE?', "#{letter.downcase}%"],:order=>'name ASC')
      end
      @users
    end

User helper
     def alphabetically_paginate(collection)
      available_letters = User.find_by_group
      content_tag(:ul, safe(alphabetical_links_to(available_letters)),
                  :class => "pagination")
     end

```
 def safe(content)
  if content.respond_to?(:html_safe)
    return content.html_safe
  end
  content
 end

 def alphabetical_links_to(available_letters)
    available_letters = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  ('A'..'Z').map do |letter|
    content_tag(:li, paginated_letter(available_letters, letter))
  end.join(" ")
 end

  def paginated_letter(available_letters, letter)
    if available_letters.include?(letter)
      link_to(letter, "#{request.path}?letter=#{letter}")
    else
      letter
    end
  end  
end
```

views

```
-('A'..'Z').each do |char|
          -if char == user.name[0]
            = link_to :action => 'char'
  =alphabetically_paginate(@users)
```

the views is incomplete as I am not sure how to proceed at the moment... I am thinkking about refreshing the page and display the list with only the A or B etc         like a seaarch page

Comment: What gems have you tried this with? will_paginate can do this without any problem. Also, what specific errors are you coming across? What version of Rails? Does you initial query give you the results you expect? In short - more details please.

Comment: I tried with the alphabetically_paginate gem found in the rubygems.org... I searched heavily on will_paginate option but I only saw that there was a patch floating around for it but couldn't find any evidence of it. As for result... I get no errors... its just that the page comes out with nonclickable alphabets... its as if the call on the sql doesn't work but It work... I have rails 3.0 and REE.. Don't mentions about trying to update my rails as this is not possible at this moment. rails and ruby are too integrated into my other codes for me to pick it apart and update it.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554755/rails-alphabetical-pagination-navigation Also, I would suggest using a true rails query rather than a find_by_sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit late to the party, but it might help other users. I've created a gem that allows for alphabetical pagination using SQL queries here: https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate

It's as simple as:

### Controller

```
 def index
    @users, @alphaParams = User.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {db_mode: true, db_field: "name"})
 end
```

### View

```
<%= alphabetical_paginate @alphaParams %>
```

Hope it helps.